# Norm of a principal ideal

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to prove $N(\sigma(x)\mathcal O_k) = $$N(x\mathcal O_k) $ where $N(I)$ is the number $|\frac{\mathcal O_k}{I}|$ and $ x\mathcal O_k $ is the principal ideal generated by $x$. $\sigma \in Gal(K/Q)$

As $ \sigma(\mathcal O_k)= \mathcal O_k $.

Can I say $|\frac{\mathcal O_k}{x\mathcal O_k}| = |\frac{\sigma (\mathcal O_k)}{\sigma(x\mathcal O_k)}|$? and hence $N(\sigma(x)\mathcal O_k) = $$N(x\mathcal O_k) $.

I want to prove this with out considering $\mathbb Z$ basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want the reasoning to be a bit more explicit.

Can you find an explicit isomorphism ${\cal O}_K/x{\cal O}_K\cong{\cal O}_K/\sigma(x){\cal O}_K$?

Inspiration: already on hand you have an isomorphism $\sigma:K\to K$.

Comment: Thanks, can I define map from $\cal O_k$ to $\cal O_k$ mod $\sigma (x)$ by $ a$ to $\sigma a$ mod $\sigma x$

Comment: Yes. Well, $a\bmod x$ to $\sigma a\bmod\sigma x$.

Comment: Ohh, thanks for the solution, some times I miss very simple solutions.